# How to calculate what pixel width the webview display port will be?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have an app, that contains a webview that loads a site from my server. The site has an interactive graphic at the top of it, that constantly changes through js on the site, and I need to know what width to initially make it in the php that sets it up.

I have been doing this with a js redirect that adds the width of the browser to the url vars, but I'd prefer if I could figure out what the width would be in the Android app and add it to the url vars there, to remove the need for that redirect. But the width of the display whch I've been trying to use seems to be much larger than the viewport. I assume due to the scale the webview decides on.

I have set the viewport meta tag in the site HTML to be initial-scale=1.0 , how can I go about getting the actual pixel width of the viewport in the app before the website is actually loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: you dont need to redirect -- check here on how to get the screens width and height using js -- https://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewportwindow-size-width-and-height-javascript

Comment: I am getting the width and height with JS, but I need it in the PHP, and the only way I'm aware of to pass it to the php is to the page first without knowing it, detecting it with JS and then reloading it with a new GET var the PHP can read.

Comment: cant you set the width to 0px in php and then set the width in js. another way is to store the width using cookies